# Visual Studio 2010: creating pages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datatable

I am working on a website in VS2010 and I have a datatable that has over 10,000 rows in it, all in a single column.  (the entries are the different login IDs for all the employees at my company)   Currently I am displaying all the entries in a single column of a gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" BackColor="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False"    GridLines="Horizontal">       
<Columns>
< asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField = "NTlogin" HeaderText = "Users" DataNavigateUrlFields = "NTlogin" DataNavigateUrlFormatString = "FCS3UserInfo.aspx?user={0}" /> 
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

What I would like to do is place these entries over a number of pages.  So if on a given day the dataTable has 9,999 entries there is 5 pages, but if it has 10,001 entries there are 6 pages of users and so on.   If possible I would like to have an even number of users between the pages.

If someone could point me in the direction of a tutorial that would help I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Paging](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs). Look through that tutorial and it may push you in the right direction.